# Angular2 Http request 401 -> 200

Tags: authentication, oauth, xmlhttprequest, angular

I'm working on an angular2 project and made a simple HTTP get request. For authentication we are using OAuth and we are sending the authorization header with the request.

When sending the request WITH the authorization header:

```
In chrome developer tools (network tab): 401 unauthorized
In javascript (observable<response> from angular2 Http.get): response.status = 200
```

When sending the request WITHOUT the authorization header:

```
In chrome developer tools (network tab): 401 unauthorized
In javascript (observable<response> from angular2 Http.get): response.status = 401
```

Does anybody know this is an angular2 issue, or is it default behaviour???

Comment: Can you add a little code to show how you're making the call. Also have you tried to use the network tab in Chrome to see if the headers are being passed correctly.  I'm looking into a similar issue, as far as I can see the headers I'm setting aren't being passed in my request, and I also get the strange behavior that my catch method is being called but when I examine the response I have a status code of 200 even though I can see that the server returned 403.  I'll post the code in a second comment

Comment: `let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        headers.append('X-Session-Id', 'hello');
        
        return this._http.get(depotsUrl, {headers: headers})
            .map(this.mapResponse)
            .catch(this.catchBadResponse));`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you solve it yet?